# Synonyms for the word "chronos" with spelling similarity

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

[Chronos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronos) is defined as:

> Chronos (/ˈkroʊnɒs/; Greek: Χρόνος, "time", pronounced [kʰrónos], also transliterated as Khronos or Latinised as Chronus) is the personification of Time in pre-Socratic philosophy and later literature. Chronos governed linear, chronological time, contrasted with the other Greek word for time, kairos, meaning the indeterminate moment that is right for something to occur.[1]

'Chronos' is the root of time and the stem of multiple words, such as:

> Synchronously
>   Asynchronously
>   Isochrounous
>   Chronology
>   Chronicle
>   Chronic

I come with a problem of failing to visualize it and concretize it in mind.

In contrast, 'Time' has a simple and concrete image originited from 'tide'.They share spelling similarity.
[tide | Origin and meaning of tide by Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tide)

I tried to associate to 'Change' which shares the  same prefix 'Ch' with 'Chronos', since the nature of time might be 'Changing'.

Nevertheless, it seem not convincing.

Is there a concrete cencept to portray 'time' with spelling similarity with 'Chronos'?

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of "chronology"?

Comment: I've read this several times and I'm honestly not sure what you're asking.  Is there some other concept that portrays "time" that's spelled like "Chronos", but isn't "Chronos"?  Chronology, chronometer, chronicle?  But I'm not sure what you mean by "portray time".

Comment: Portray time is to describe 'time' as a drawing or painting as a concrete object @stangdon

Comment: A chronometer is a very accurate watch. Visualise a very expensive watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this problem. I'd try to think of a word that shares the same root with *chronos* and is also very closely associated with the concept of time. One such word would be [**chronic**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chronic). Something that's chronic is there all the time. For example, a chronic illness is one that never goes away—it's present at all times. Then, I would make a simple sentence or two containing both words, *chronic* and *time*, and learn it (or them) by heart:

> He has been a **chronic** asthmatic his entire life. He has been suffering from asthma for a long, long **time** now.

Answer (score 2):

You could always visualise Chronos himself:
[image]

Image from [here](http://davidknightwrites.blogspot.co.id/2012/03/kairos-moments.html)